# Ajax value with redirect and echo to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have developed the website using jquery & PHP, I have created a page using HTML, / PHP so what I want is if I click on submit, item ajax should send value to PHP variable and then execute index.php and get that value to another page.

Please help me to resolve the issues.

So far, I have tried the following:

**index.php**

my Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var val = $("#number").val();
        $.ajax ({
             type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { val : val },            
            dataType:'text',
            success: function( result ) {           
            // window.location.href = 'ajax.php'; 
            // alert(result);           
             }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

my HTML Code

```
    <form name="numbers" id="numbers">
     <input type="text" name="number" id="number" >
     <button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**ajax.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
 $_SESSION['val'] = $_POST['val'];
print_r($_SESSION);
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're using `submit`, then choose a `method="GET"` / `"POST"`, you wanna use `GET` then GET. You don't need to bind a click with AJAX during submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the value in session and redirect the user to other page and get data from session at other pages.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $_GET['val'];
?>
```

Your HTML code must be like that

```
    <form name="numbers" id="numbers">
     <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
     <button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

For redirect to other page you can use like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var val = "Hi";
        $.ajax ({
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: { val : val },
            success: function( result ) {     
             window.location.href = 'url';            
             }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208895/discussion-on-answer-by-asif-chaudhary-ajax-value-with-redirect-and-echo-to-page).

Answer (score 0):

in this if you click button its refresh the page because you using input type="submit" on button , so just change it to input type="button"

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="submit">
```

and if you want to keep input type="submit" as you already did then just add prevent default to jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    var val = "Hi";
    $.ajax ({
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: { val : val },
        success: function( result ) {                
         }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but this is also not full filing my result.

Comment: if you just want to redirect and echo then remove ajax code and just place this code <form method="post" action="ajax.php"> <input type="text" name="number" id="number"> <input type="submit" id="btn" value="submit"> </form> and on ajax.php use echo $_POST['number'];

Comment: I have different type of requirement so that is the reason I have used AJAX here.Scenario is I have page call view all records in that last column button is edit when user click on edit button page should redirect to edit page with id or value

Answer (score 0):

you can use session

in ajax.php you have to add:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_GET['val'];
$_SESSION['val'] = $_GET['val'];
?>
```

and use variable $_SESSION['val'] to any page

Comment: Getting error : Notice: Undefined index: val in C:\xampp\htdocs\Dir\ajax.php on line 4